# Show that if $u=g(x,y)$ and $v=h(x,y)$ then $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} = \frac{\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}}{J}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, jacobian

where J is the Jacobian $\frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (x,y)}$

First:

$$
\frac{\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}}{J} = \frac{\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}}
$$

I do this:

$$
\frac{\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}}{J} = \frac{1}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - \frac{\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}}}
$$

I then expand this:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}
$$

Then the above becomes:

$$
\frac{\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}}{J} = \frac{1}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}}
$$

But following this logic (which is clearly wrong):

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
$$

And so:

$$
\frac{\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}}{J} = \frac{1}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}} = \frac{1}{0}
$$

Comment: The chain rule only applies to functions that can actually be written as composed functions, but there is no way to write $y$ as a function of $x$ alone, so the problem occurs when you introduce $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$.

Comment: Consider this simpler "contradiction". Suppose $f(x,y)= x$, then
$1 = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} =0$ ??

Comment: What are $x$ and $y$ functions of here?

Comment: @Jamal They are independent variables, but I guess x = G(u,v) and y = H(u,v)